# NSDateFormatter returning nil on dateFromString

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

`_savedTime` is logging as "2012-01-30 09:40:29 +0000" as a string.

But it's crashing "SIGBRT" when trying to convert to NSDate.

```
NSString * _savedTime = [_savedAlarm objectForKey:@"AlarmTime"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate* time1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:_savedTime];
```

Breaking on the last line with error:

> -[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa10c540

Help!  My formatting looks correct, but maybe I just need a separate set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `_savedTime` (or the value of the key `@AlarmTime`) is already an `NSDate`.

There is no conversion needed so you can just do:

```
NSDate* _savedTime = [_savedAlarm objectForKey:@"AlarmTime"];
```

The date formatter assumes the parameter passed to `dateFromString:` is an `NSString` and tries to call `length` on it and fails.